# Remove selective JSON's from JSON DF array using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to remove multiple json from the json array, I have a json in below source format as shown below.
I have a list that contains the list of device id that need to kept in the json array, rest need to be deleted.
For example as shown in my source json I have 3 `dev_id 100010100 , 200020200 and 300030300`.

I have python list `device_id_list=[200020200,300030300]`, My final JSON array should contain only 2 json in the json array, the json with dev_id= 100010100 will be deleted as shown in the output json.

I trying one option that might not be optimal, My approach is reading the json as string instead json as shown below.

```
df = spark.read.text("path\\iot-sensor.json")
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
value:string
```

I have written an udf to delete the json those are not present in the `device_id_list`. It is deleting the `dev_id` which are not present and returning the json as string.

I want this string i.e. `dataframe df2` to be converted into JSON , with the same source json schema `(df2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [iot_station: array] (Sorce Schema) )` because the schema for source and output json should be same and also if there is better solution for this issue please share.

UDF:

```
def drop_dev_id(jsonResponse,dict_keys):
    try:
        data = json.loads(jsonResponse)
        i = 0
        n = len(data['iot_station'])
        while (i < n):
            if data['iot_station'][i]["dev_id"] not in dict_keys:
                data['iot_station'].pop(i)       
                n -= 1
            else:
                i += 1
        return data
           
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception --> ' + str(e))


def drop_dev_id_udf(dict_keys):
     return udf(lambda row: drop_dev_id(row,dict_keys), StringType())
     
df2 = df.select('value',drop_dev_id_udf(dict_keys)('value')).select('<lambda>(value)')
df2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
<lambda>(value):string
```

**Source JSON**

```
{
  "iot_station": [
    {
      "dev_id": 100010100,
      "device1": dev_val1,
      "device2": "dev_val2",
      "device3": dev_val3,
      "device4": "dev_val4",
      "stationid": [
        {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
        }
      ],
      "geospat": {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
      }
    },
    {
      "dev_id": 200020200,      
      "device1": dev_val1,
      "device2": "dev_val2",
      "device3": dev_val3,
      "device4": "dev_val4",
      "stationid": [
        {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
        }
      ],
      "geospat": {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
    }
    },
    {
      "dev_id": 300030300,      
      "device1": dev_val1,
      "device2": "dev_val2",
      "device3": dev_val3,
      "device4": "dev_val4",
      "stationid": [
        {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
        }
      ],
      "geospat": {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
    }
    }
    ]
}
```

**Output JSON:**

```
{
  "iot_station": [
    {
      "dev_id": 200020200,      
      "device1": dev_val1,
      "device2": "dev_val2",
      "device3": dev_val3,
      "device4": "dev_val4",
      "stationid": [
        {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
        }
      ],
      "geospat": {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
    }
    },
    {
      "dev_id": 300030300,      
      "device1": dev_val1,
      "device2": "dev_val2",
      "device3": dev_val3,
      "device4": "dev_val4",
      "stationid": [
        {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
        }
      ],
      "geospat": {
          "id": id_val,
          "idrs": idrs_val,
          "idrq": "idrq_val",
          "idrx": "idrx_val"
    }
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: use `return json.dumps(data)`?

Comment: @mck iI tried your option it is still showing df2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
<lambda>(value):string i need  df2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [iot_station: array] (Sorce Schema), If you feel this is not good approach to solve this problem, please recommend a  better solution I am open to new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need UDF for what you want to achieve here. Just load it as normal JSON instead of text and use [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter) function to filter the array column `iot_station` :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = spark.read.json("path/iot-sensor.json", multiLine=True)

device_id_list = [str(i) for i in [200020200, 300030300]]

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "iot_station",
    F.expr(f"""
        filter(
            iot_station, 
            x -> x.dev_id in ({','.join(device_id_list)})
        )
    """)
)

# check filtered json
df1.select(F.col("iot_station").getItem("dev_id").alias("dev_id")).show(truncate=False)

#+----------------------+
#|dev_id                |
#+----------------------+
#|[200020200, 300030300]|
#+----------------------+
```